# How to await(?) passed data prior to calculation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing, calculator

Currently my app is designed to accept parameters like weight, height, age, gender, etc. I am trying to make it calculate two different versions of the persons weight (ideal and adjusted) but cant seem to make my app do that under the calculator model and instead can only figure out how calculate the ideal and adjusted weights by doing the math on the input screen which is cluttering up my application. Any advice on how to make a widget or make the calculator wait for the inputs (weight and height) rather than doing the math on the input page prior to hitting calculate?

**Input Screen**

```
class InputScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _InputScreenState createState() =>
      _InputScreenState();
}

class _InputScreenState
    extends State<InputScreen> {
  final TextEditingController weightController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController heightController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController creatController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();
  final MyUnit heightUnit = MyUnit();
  final MyUnit weightUnit = MyUnit(imperial: 'lbs', metric: 'kg');
  final MyUnit ageUnit = MyUnit(imperial: 'years', metric: 'years');
  final MyButton selected = MyButton(title3: 'Female', title4: 'Male');

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    weightController.dispose();
    heightController.dispose();
    creatController.dispose();
    heightUnit.dispose();
    weightUnit.dispose();
    ageUnit.dispose();
    selected.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipPath(
            clipper: MyClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 250,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: kHeaderGradient,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('images/virus.png'),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  AppBar(
                    leading: null,
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }),
                    ],
                    title: Text(
                      'Creatinine Clearance',
                      style: kHeaderTextStyle,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    elevation: 0.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              ValueListenableBuilder<Option>(
                valueListenable: selected,
                builder: (context, option, _) => MakeButtons(
                  num0: 3,
                  num1: 5,
                  makeButtonWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
                  selected: option,
                  onChanged: (newOption) => selected.option = newOption,
                ),
              ),
              InputRow(
                myUnit: heightUnit,
                inputParameter: 'height',
                textField: heightController,
                colour: kOrangePantone,
              ),
              InputRow(
                myUnit: weightUnit,
                inputParameter: 'weight',
                textField: weightController,
                colour: kRoyalPurple,
              ),
              InputRow(
                myUnit: ageUnit,
                inputParameter: 'Age',
                textField: ageController,
                colour: kDogwoodRose,
              ),
              RoundedButton(
                title: 'Calculate',
                onPressed: () {
                  String inputHeight = heightController.text;
                  String inputWeight = weightController.text;
                  String inputAge = ageController.text;

                  double imperialHeight = double.parse(inputHeight) * 2.54;
                  double metricHeight = double.parse(inputHeight);
                  double imperialWeight = double.parse(inputWeight) / 2.2;
                  double metricWeight = double.parse(inputWeight);

                 
                  double age = double.parse(inputAge);
                  double multiplier = selected.title == 'Female' ? 0.85 : 1.0;
                  double height = heightUnit.unitType == 'cm'
                      ? metricHeight
                      : imperialHeight;
                  double weight = weightUnit.unitType == 'cm'
                      ? metricWeight
                      : imperialWeight;

//- Calculations that I need in a calculator model//

                  double idealWeight = selected.title == 'Female'
                      ? (45 +
                          2.3 *
                              (heightUnit.unitType == 'cm'
                                  ? ((double.parse(inputHeight) - 152.4) / 2.54)
                                  : (double.parse(inputHeight) - 60)))
                      : (50 +
                          2.3 *
                              (heightUnit.unitType == 'cm'
                                  ? ((double.parse(inputHeight) - 152.4) / 2.54)
                                  : (double.parse(inputHeight) - 60)));

                  double adjustWeight = (weightUnit.unitType == 'kg'
                      ? (double.parse(inputWeight) - idealWeight) * 0.4 +
                          idealWeight
                      : ((double.parse(inputWeight) / 2.2) - idealWeight) *
                              0.4 +
                          idealWeight);

                  print(weight);
                  print(idealWeight);
                  print(adjustWeight);

                  Calculator calc;
                  calc = Calculator(
                    height: height,
                    weight: weight,
                    age: age,
                    genderMultiplier: multiplier,
                    ideal: idealWeight,
                    adjust: adjustWeight,
                  );

                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ResultsScreen(
                        weightModified: calc.calculate(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 80);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 80);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Calculator model**

```
class Calculator {
  Calculator({
    this.height,
    this.weight,
    this.age,
    this.genderMultiplier,
    this.ideal,
    this.adjust,
  });

  double height;
  double weight;
  double age;
  double genderMultiplier;
  double ideal;
  double adjust;
  

  double _weightModified


  String calculate() {
    _weightModified = weight + ideal - adjust * genderMultiplier;
    return _weightModified.toStringAsFixed(1);

  }
}
```

**Results Screen**

```
class ResultsScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  ResultsScreen({
    @required this.weightModifiedResult,
  });

  final String weightModifiedResult;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Your Result',
            ),
          ),
          ReuseableCard(
            bgColor: kGreyBackgroundColor,
            cardChild: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  weightModifiedResult,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          RoundedButton(
            title: 'Re-Calc',
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if I quite understand the question, but were you looking for removing the 'calculate' button and instead would like your app to wait for user input on the parameters and calculate it automatically?

If so, you can "listen" for changes on your TextFields by using [onChanged() callback](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes) and calculate the ideal/adjusted weights.

Comment: I have the "listen" function already set up using the "MyButton selected" parameter on the input screen. I have uploaded a picture to hopefully demonstrate what I am trying to do: https://ibb.co/CBnB4wc . Currently, when the calculate button is pressed, the math is preformed on input screen rather than the calculator screen. The only way I can access the math at the moment is with the ideal and adjust parameters on the calculator screen which pulls from the input screen. I tried using Future, async, and await but no luck. Does that help?